# Duality transformation in Kitaev's quantum double models

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, topological-order

In Kitaev's quantum double models (https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9707021.pdf), it is well known that the vertex operators $A_g$ and the plaquette operators $B_h$ are dual to each other, so there should be some local transformation of the physical qudits which will implement $A_g \leftrightarrow B_h$. Does anyone know of an explicit form of this transformation?